# mongodb query where nested object has > 0 properties

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

EDIT - See the end of the question for one way to do it:

I have a mongo object with properties like:

`{ something: { name: "asdf", childThing: {} } }`

and

`{ something: { name: "jklh", childThing: {"type": "blah"} } }`

How can I write a query that will find the object `somethingElse` based on the fact that `count(somethingElse.childThing.keys) > 0`

I tried this but it's only for arrays, I guess, because it returns all records:

`{ 'childThing': { $exists: true, $not: {$size: 0} } }`

**EDIT: I figured out one way to do this:**

`{ 'something.childThing': { $not: {$eq: {} } } }`

This just matches all documents that have a non-empty value for that child

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) operator to transform the `childThing` object to an array:

> Converts a document to an array. The return array contains a element
>   for each field/value pair in the original document.

This way you can get its size (which is the number of fields) and match it to being not 0:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: {
    "childKeyCount": { "$size": { "$objectToArray": "$something.childThing" } }
  }},
  { $match: { "childKeyCount": { "$ne": 0 } } }
  // { $project: { "childKeyCount": false } }
])
```

Given this input:

```
[
  { "something" : { "name" : "asdf", "childThing" : {  } } }
  { "something" : { "name" : "jklh", "childThing" : { "type" : "blah" } } }
]
```

it gives:

```
[
  {
    "something" : { "name" : "jklh", "childThing" : { "type" : "blah" } },
    "childKeyCount" : 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)** operator in your `find()` query as it allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language. You would need an expression that transforms the object with the unknown keys to an array using **[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)** and calculate the size of the array with **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)** to check the numbers of keys in the object. Once you get the size then run a comparison check with **[`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/)** to be used as the condition for **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)**:

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({ 
    "$expr": {
        "$gt": [ { "$size": { "$objectToArray": "$something.childThing" } }, 0]
    }
})
```